# Does JFrame work on Android / iOS?

Tags: java, android, ios, jframe, game-development

Recently I have been programming a game in Java without using anything like OpenGL, I have just been using Java and Java alone. I use JFrame for some stuff in my game and was wondering if it works on Android or iOS in case I want to make mobile games.

I am rather new to programming in Java, I know some of the basics but I just don't know all the answers and searching online isn't helping that much. This also sounds really nooby, but does JFrame work on Mac & Linux too? I have heard that it does, but if not I might consider learning how to use OpenGL or something, but some of the tutorials on OpenGL I've found turn out to be bad.

Comment: Please focus on your problem and define your question more precisely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately java swing is not supported by android. This means swing classes will not be usable in android environments so classes like JFrame will show up as errors when you move it over to android studio. Android does support OpenGL and this would be usable. Android does its UI through XML and it might be possible to use this. but it will require many changes.  You will be able to move over all of your classes that do not reference external libraries, or libraries like java swing. You will need to re-write the parts of your code that deal with the JFrames though :/